# Convert datetime to a fixed date of the month including the time - mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to convert the date time to a fixed day of the month including the time.

For example, the conversion dates should be as follows:

- `2016-03-24 04:31:21` converted to `2016-03-15 00:00:00`
- `2016-03-16 12:11:20` converted to `2016-03-15 00:00:00`
- `2015-11-24 05:09:12` converted to `2015-11-15 00:00:00`
- `2015-09-05 06:16:13` converted to `2015-09-15 00:00:00`

The day and time value should remain constant.

The following does the day part:

```
CAST(DATE_FORMAT(start_date_time ,'%Y-%m-15') as date) as created_month
```

I don't know how to include time as well here. Appreciate help

Comment: You don't need to add time, since you want to have `00:00:00` anyway. So just cast to `DATETIME`. Probably this: `CAST(DATE_FORMAT(start_date_time ,'%Y-%m-15') as datetime)`, or if it doesn't work, this: `CAST(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(start_date_time ,'%Y-%m-15'), ' 00:00:00') as datetime)`.

Comment: You can try something like that : `    CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(CAST(start_date_time as datetime)), '-', MONTH(CAST(start_date_time, as date)), '-15 00:00:00') as datetime)`

Comment: @GolezTrol thank you. You are right, it was simply converting to 00's without adding any time component.. Thank you..

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure which of the versions you used, but if you like you can post the final solution as a formal answer (instead of a comment like this), so future visitors can easily read it. I'd do it myself, but I don't know which of my suggestions works best, and I can't test it atm.