# Convert date to a month in one time zone when time saved is in GMT - SQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

This is related to an earlier question that I had here: [Convert datetime to a fixed date of the month including the time - mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406568/convert-datetime-to-a-fixed-date-of-the-month-including-the-time-mysql?noredirect=1#comment60429476_36406568)

I am raising a another question because this is regarding the timezone component in the datetime.

I have a list of date time values that are stored in GMT. For the purpose of a report, I want to convert the dates to a single date of a month. (which was the subject of the previous thread I mentioned above). What I also would like to do is the take the time zone into consideration. I will explain.

The date field is always stored in GMT. But the report is generated for the HQ that is in EST. So when there the dates are converted to a single date time (again, part of the previous thread) only the dates that fall into that month in EST (not GMT) should be changed to that month.

For example, let us say I have this date stored in the table:
2016-04-01 00:03:07 (GMT). But for a person sitting in Eastern time zone this is created in the month of March. So, when I do the conversion of the dates to a specific date of a month, this date should be converted to 2016-03-15 00:00:00 and not 2016-04-15 00:00:00

Pretty challenging to me!

I need this in this format as I am integrating with a third party application

Answer (score 0):

[CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) should be able to convert to your required timezone. Then, do the rest of the operations on the result instead of doing them on th original date.